# two different values of x in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

Why does the first alert show 3 and the second alert show 1?  I realize that `this` changes the scope but isn't `go()` and `foo.baz.bar()` calling the same thing?

```
var x = 3;

var foo = {
    x: 2,
    baz: {
        x: 1,
        bar: function() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}

var go = foo.baz.bar;

alert(go());
alert(foo.baz.bar());
```

Comment: `go` scope is `window`, `foo.baz.bar` scope is `foo.baz.bar`

Comment: They are calling the same function but the function's `this` is bound to different things. Read about [`this` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @Isaac that cleared it up for me , thanks

Answer (score 1):

The execution context of the first alert is the Window object. The execution context of the second alert is the function called bar.  That's it. The Execution Context is the bit to understand.

Here are the details: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript assigns the definition of `this` at run time. This means that it doesn't analyze the code around it unless you're explicit, like how you are when you use `foo.baz.bar`. Using `go` immediately invokes

```
function() {
   return this.x;
}
```

Note that this particular statement is interpreted to be outside of the `foo` object. Its context is actually `window` or `global` (depending on your dev environment).